# Django template loop over dictionary.items with "items" as key

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary in my template that I want to loop through in the usual way

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
```

But in dictionary I have a key called `'items'`, so my loop return the value of dictionary['items'] and tries to unpack the result as key, value.

How can I tell Django to use the function `items` instead of accessing the key?

Comment: the word 'items' is just too generic, maybe you should try to find a more specific name for your key, it would avoid this problem and make your code more readable

Comment: My problem was that I didn't create the keys myself but got them from an external API. I just wanted to print all key-value pairs nicely for viewing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `dictionary.iteritems` instead? I don't think there's a better way.

If you have no control over dictionary keys, the only safe way is a custom tag for iterating over dicts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life. I just can't belive that I didn't try iteritems mysfelf and that I couldn't find that in the docs :/